# nltk Regex tokenizer not capturing unicode chars

Tags: regex, nltk, tokenize

I'm having an issue with nltk regex tokenizer not capturing some characters in unicode string. See screenshot below.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJJRC.png)

How can i get the tokenizer to capture the full words?

The code works fine on my RHEL 7.3 laptop, but not on an webbased jupyter notebook. Anyone have any idea what is not working here?

Comment: What if you just use `u'ΰαβγδεζ test'`? If you use Python 3.x, you do not need `re.UNICODE`, it is required in Python 2.x to make `\w` and other shorthand character classes Unicode aware.

Comment: `u'ΰαβγδεζ test'` only prints out `[u'test']`, no unicode is captured. This is on Python 2.7

Comment: Is your file saved with UTF8 encoding? Try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file. See [this demo](http://rextester.com/IVLR71790).

Comment: Yes i tried this. Just ran your demo code in my notebook, still just printing `test`. This is a Jupyter and Spark notebook environment on IBM Data Science Experience, must be something in the environment that is not right then

Comment: I changed the notebook kernel to use Python 3.5 instead which fixed the problem. Still quite strange, as it should work with Python 2.7